# Grunt.js output and write contents of folder to file?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

### Goal:

Dynamically include `/static/js/**/*.js` and `/static/css/**/*.css` files too `<head>`

### Method:

I am using client side templating partials, so in this example, I would like to write filepaths of everything in:

`/static/js/**/*.js` too `/templates/head.js.dust`
`/static/css/**/*.css` too `/templates/head.css.dust`

File paths are not enough of course. I need a way to preprocess the the output so that every "file" is wrapped by appropriate tags like:

```
<!-- /templates/head.js.dust -->
<script src="/static/js/assests/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/assests/jquery_ui.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/app.js"></script>
...

<!-- /templates/head.css.dust -->
<link src="/static/css/assests/jquery_ui.css"/>
<link src="/static/css/app.css"/>
...
```

### Question:

Is there a grunt module out there that already does something like this?

**Bonus Points:** *How do I even get started building something like this if it does not?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so in a fairly easy way:

```
grunt.registerMultiTask("assetAppend", "Append JS/CSS assets to a file", function() {
    var paths = grunt.file.expand( this.data.paths ),
        out = this.data.output,
        contents = "";

    paths.forEach(function( path ) {
        if ( /\.js$/i.test( path ) ) {
            contents += '<script src="' + path + '"></script>';
        } else if ( /\.css$/i.test( path )) {
            contents += '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=' + path + ' />';
        }
    });

    grunt.file.write( out, contents );
});

grunt.initConfig({
    assetAppend: {
        js: {
            paths: ["static/js/**/*.js"],
            output: "head.js.dust"
        },
        css: {
            paths: ["static/css/**/*.css"],
            output: "head.css.dust"
        }
    }
});
```

*This example is now part of my plugin **[grunt-contrib-assetpush](https://github.com/gustavohenke/grunt-contrib-assetpush)***

Comment: This looks exactly like what I need! I will try this tomorrow for sure! Word of advice - although this may not seem like a useful tool, if people knew it existed (I hardly believe I was the first that was looking for something like this), they would use it. I would open-source on github and throw it into the http://gruntjs.com/plugins bank before someone else does =) ... It really could be a BIG time saver as a module that you can config.

Comment: Thank you very much! There you go with this plugin: https://github.com/gustavohenke/grunt-contrib-assetpush